# How to figure out that user has changed password or not via mail FIREBASE

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to find out that the user has changed the password or not via mail.
I am registering user with email

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(id, pass);
```

and if user asks for forgot password
i send forgot email by

```
mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
```

But I cannot say or figure it out that the user has changed it via email or not?

How is it possible to figure out that the password is changed or not via email?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same case few days ago when I required to save user's password in my Database too. But when user change his password via Link it was difficult for me to get user's new changed password. So I did it in the following way

While signing in through App save user's password in `SharedPreferences` **after successful Firebase authentication**. So you will always have latest user's password in your SharedPreferences. And now in your case to check user really changed his password or not, you can check if the password which is going to be saved on signin in `SharedPreferences` is different from the previous one, Its mean it was changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect whether the user clicked the link in the password reset email, consider setting up your own [handler for the email actions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). Have a look at the document for inspiration, or at the default page that is used when you don't provide a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a complete listener to `sendPasswordResetEmail()`, and if the email has been sent, you can write in your database inside that user ID a value that will tell you that the password has been reset.

If you need to check that the user has changed the password, you can check at your database whether the user did or not.

For example, a basic structure to check that the user has changed passwords could be this

```
- UserID
 |__ passwordReset
    |_____ passwordResetPushID
          |___ changed : TIMESTAMP
...
```

Remember that FirebaseAuth `getCurrentUser()` could be null at the time of changing the password if you are doing it from the login flow, but it's not going to be any problem if you do it inside your app after the user is logged in.

For the first case, you will need a little workaround, maybe storing into `sharedPrefs` the latest user logged in ID.

### Edit

As Frank's comments, you will need a sort of function that is triggered after the user has reset the password in the browser, this solution will only let you know whenever the `sendPasswordResetEmail()` has been triggered but not a confirmation that the user has completed the password change, to do that, follow Frank's answer.

Comment: The *sending* of the email does not reset the password. I think OP is trying to detect whether the password reset link in the email was clicked.